# Logging in users through Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-active-directory

I have a website which allows admin users to connect to their Office 365 account.  From this I can read the calendars of all users and also get a user list.  This all works fine.

The user rights that I ask are:

```
Sign users in  
Read calendars in all mailboxes  
Read directory data  
Read all users' full profiles  
Sign in and read user profile  
Enable sign-on and read users' profiles  
Read directory data
```

And these are the scopes: ["openid", "Calendars.Read", "User.Read", "User.Read.All", "offline_access"]

Getting all the users works fine with this call:
    https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

However now I want to enhance the features so users are logged in automatically.  So all I need is a call to get the current profile of the user so I can match the ID with the ID's in the application...  I found this call and tried executing it:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

But I'm getting back this:

784: unexpected token at '{
  "error": {
    "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "Resource 'a6787ee0-4ba1-421f-a19c-beadf693b9eb' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "c767c4ee-0912-4744-a7e4-59a8a23626fe",
      "date": "2016-10-22T01:26:54"
    }
  }
}'

What am I missing here?

Just to make sure, can somebody confirm that what I plan to do is possible:

- Have the admin user authenticate and give access (see rights above)
- Sync the users so they exist in my webapp as well (and I have their ID's)
- When another user is already signed in to MS, I want to detect this when they go to my webpage and sign him in as well in my webapp

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, it seems you were using the app-only token which acquire using **client credential flow** to call the Microsoft Graph. There is no user context info in the app-only token. So it is not support to call this REST using this kind of token.

And based on the description, you were authenticating the users with OpenId connect protocol. To get the user info, we can retrieve these information from the id_token. And if you were developing ASP.Net web application, you also can get there information from `ClaimsPrincipal` class easily.

> Have the admin user authenticate and give access (see rights above)
>
> Sync the users so they exist in my webapp as well (and I have their ID's)
>
> When another user is already signed in to MS, I want to detect this when they go to my webpage and sign him in as well in my webapp

The app is protected by Azure AD. So if you mean that the users already signed in to MS with Azure AD account, yes your app could detect this and sign-in the users.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Where I am today is: admin gives consent (for everybody with the rights I specified above).  After this users are imported from Azure.  They do need to sign in manually today.  After they login, the system is able to get their calendar items (but it only know whose items to get because that user is logged in).  It's a Ruby application. You write that 'yes your app could detect this'.  How (with which call) is this possible?  Should this call be made totally independant of the token I already got? I want to avoid the need to grant access again by each user.

Comment: To get the user context info, you need to use the **OAuth 2.0 code grant flow** instead of **Client Credential flow**. And when your users sign-in your app which integrate with Azure AD, it will redirect to Azure AD. And the Azure AD will send the cookie to the client if the users sign-in. So when the users try to sign-in the app which users already sign-in, it is not require to enter username/password again. More detail about using **openId Connect** to acquire the access token, you can refer [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-protocols-oidc/)